# How to search by name attribute?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find an input element `<input id="telephone" name="telephone">`. I tried `soup.find('input', name='telephone')` and didn't find it. However `soup.find('input', id='telephone')` works fine. I think the problem is that 'name' has two meanings, the name of the tag and the name attribute. So, how can I search by the name attribute?

---

Obviously in my example I can search by the id attribute, but that's not there in my actual predicament.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `attrs` parameter.  For example:

```
soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'telephone'})
```

or, more simply in your case:

```
soup.find('input', {'name': 'telephone'})
```

(See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

You don't have to pass the tag name (`'input'` in your case) - you can just search by attributes alone - but I've included it to match the details of your question.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: or just simply `soup.find('input', {'name': 'telephone'})`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that you wrote.

```
soup.find('input', name='telephone');
```

Would you try to use this?

```
soup.find('input[name="telephone"]');
```

Hope it works.

Comment: check here [http://jsfiddle.net/ChoHongRae/SsL4m/](http://jsfiddle.net/ChoHongRae/SsL4m/)